# Changing properties of an object and piping mismatches

Tags: powershell

I guess i have a general missunderstanding of how to work with objects in that way, so maybe someone can give me a hand.

So let's proceed to my scenario where I stumbled upon this topic.
I'm having a hard time adding additional information to network adapters of a server.

The default name and description are for example
"LOM 1 Port 1" and "HP Adapter XYZ"
I renamed the adapter to from "Embedded LOM ...." to something readable like "Cluster Heartbeat"

But as the server has a lot of NICs, I thought I could be useful to keep the information what card and port it is and so I tried to write some additional information to "Description" or "InterfaceDescription" but I cannot make it work.
At the moment i'm now sure if it is impossible or if just do it wrong.

Here are some of my attemps:
(i tried "Description" and "InterfaceDescription")

```
Get-NetAdapter -Name "Cluster Heartbeat" | Set-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription "HP Adapter XYZ / LOM 1 Port 1"
Get-NetAdapter -Name "Cluster Heartbeat" | Set-ItemProperty -Name "InterfaceDescription" -Value "HP Adapter XYZ / LOM 1 Port 1"
```

It always results in a error saying

```
Set-NetAdapter : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
Set-ItemProperty : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
```

So basically I cannot do it because

- it does not take pipeline Input by default
- or there is a mismatch of the properties/parameter when piping

I would like to know how I can find out if a property is changeable and why the piping can fail with the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unable to edit the Interface Description because it is read-only. A `Get-NetAdapter | Get-Member` reveals:

```
InterfaceDescription Property string InterfaceDescription {get;}
```

If it would be editable there would also be a `set;`.